# Ellipsis on span inside table cell for max width cell

Tags: html, css

**Small update**

Note: *Target is mainly Chrome (perhaps Firefox) – as it is for an extension. But, of course, if there is an all-round solution that would be nice to know as well.*

**Another update**

Note: *Noticed that if there are no spaces in the text for `A` and it is too big, it pushes out `B`. Problem became worse and looks like I'm further from a solution then first thought. Updated sample code to allow input from user. Try sample without spaces.*

---

I am having a fixed positioned box of full width and fixed height. It is placed inside an environment of variable / dynamic width.

```
+-----------------------------+
|                             |
|                             |
[=============================] << The box.
|                             |
|                             |
...
      <-  dynamic width  ->
```

The box has two *main children* A and B. `B` takes precedence on width and are to hold all of it contents on given height, but not in a greedy way. `A` is eats remainder of space in a greedy fashion. On text-overflow in A, ellipsis should be added – and that is where I'm stuck.

Some examples.

```
1. B fills it's space, A expand to fill width.
+-------------------+--------+
| A________         | __B___ |
+-------------------+--------+

2. A has overflow, ellipsis added.
+-------------------+--------+
| A_____________... | __B___ |
+-------------------+--------+

3. B, has grown, A shrinks.
+----------------+-----------+
| A__________... | __B______ |
+----------------+-----------+
```

After fiddling around with various approaches from floats to absolute, relative and other types I finally landed on a table layout (as in CSS-table, not HTML). Can't get desired effect with other approach. If anyone know how it is OK to tell :)

#### *Problem is the ellipsis part on overflow in `A`.*

Can I somehow tweak e.g. how `A` is set up to get this?

Sample code:

***Ignore the JavaScript, it is only a convenience routine to display the over and under-flow.*** (Found it nice to have whilst editing in Firefox's Style Editor)

```js
/* Yes. It is all a mess and weird usage of variables vs this etc. */
function Hack() {
    var x     = 0,
        n     = 150,
        wrap  = document.querySelector('#wrap'),
        left  = document.querySelector('#left'),
        right = document.querySelector('#right'),
        txt   = document.querySelector('#txt'),
        ent   = document.querySelectorAll('.entry'),
        log   = document.querySelector('#log'),
        run   = document.querySelector('#run'),
        rt    = document.querySelector('#rt'),
        samp  = document.querySelector('#sample'),
        t     = samp.value
    ;
    this.rt = parseInt(rt.value) || 1000;
    function getComp(e) {
        var x = window.getComputedStyle(e, null);
        return ''+
          ~~(parseInt(x.getPropertyValue('height'))) + 'x' +
          ~~(parseInt(x.getPropertyValue('width')))
        ;
    }
    this.status = function () {
        log.textContent = 'Height / Width for:\n' +
            '  wrap  : ' + getComp(wrap) + '\n' +
            '  left  : ' + getComp(left) + '\n' +
            '  right : ' + getComp(right) + '\n' +
            '  sample: ' + getComp(txt) + '\n'
        ;
    }
    /* Change between long and short text in sample cells. */
    this.flip = function () {
        txt.textContent = x ? t : (new Array(n)).join(t);
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(ent, function (e) {
            e.textContent = x ? 'abc' : 'abcabc';
        });
        x ^= 1;
        this.status();
    }
    /* Toggle auto run. */
    this.update = function () {
        t = samp.value;
        this.rt = parseInt(rt.value);
        if (!this.rt || this.rt < 10)
            rt.value = this.rt = 100;
        clearInterval(this.ttt);
        if (run.checked)
            this.ttt = setInterval(this.flip.bind(this), this.rt);
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', this.flip.bind(this));
    run.addEventListener('click', this.update.bind(this));
    rt.addEventListener('change', this.update.bind(this));
    samp.addEventListener('keyup', this.update.bind(this));
    this.update();
}
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var hack = new Hack();
    hack.flip();
});
```

```css
*       { margin     : 0;    padding : 0;  }
#log    { margin     : 5pt;  border  : 1px solid #ccc; }
#filler { margin-top : 90px; height  : 2000px; background : #efefef; }
label,
input   { cursor     : pointer; }

/* inner elements of cells in right  -- (B)     */
.hdr,
.entry  { padding    : 2px 5px; }
.hdr    { font-weight: bold; }

#wrap { /* the red thing             -- aka (the box) */
    position   : fixed;
    top        : 135px;
    height     : 23px;
    background : #600;
    color      : #999;
    height     : 20px;
    width      : 100%;
    display    : table-row;
}
#left { /* the green thing           -- aka (A) */
    background : #044;
    display    : table-cell;
    width      : 100%;
}
#txt { /* sample text in left                   */  /* Where I want ellipsis */
    display    : block;
    height     : 20px;
    width      : 100%;
    overflow   : hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#right { /* the purple / blue thing  -- aka (B) */
    background : rgba(0,0,200,.5);
    height     : 20px;
    display    : table-cell;
    width      : 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>Click document to expand text, or auto-run:</p>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="run" checked /><label for="run">Change every </label>
<input type="number" id="rt" value="1000" step="100" /> millisecond.
Sample text: <input type="text" value=" sample" id="sample" />
</div>
<pre id="log"></pre>

<!-- The box -->

<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left">
    <span id="txt">sample <!-- ellipsis here --> </span>     
  </div>
  <div id="right">
      <span class="hdr">Foo</span><span class="entry">abcd</span>
      <span class="hdr">Bar</span><span class="entry">abcd</span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- EOF: The box -->

<div id="filler">dummy filler page height</div>
```

Comment: Ach. I notice there is a problem with existing sample as well. If text in `A` is without spaces, it will push `B` out of view ... :(

Comment: _“If text in A is without spaces, it will push B out of view ...”_ – well, it needs to be “without spaces” (or have `white-space` property applied to create non-breaking text), otherwise you won’t get an ellipsis to show to begin with, because then it will only show “sample” as many times as it fits onto one line, and then break the rest onto a second (or more) lines, which are hidden because of `overflow` setting. […]

Comment: […] But if you do make the text not break, that will collide with the table layout algorithm … in short, I don’t think you can get this to work (at least not while displaying as table-cells) without setting fixed `width`s …

Comment: @CBroe: Yes. It looks like I am further from a solution then assumed. The ellipsis was a *last touch*, merely as candy, on something I thought was OK. Bummer. Can do it in JS, but would have been soo nice to do it in CSS. – The *table cells* is not important per se. But was only way I got it "working" – or so I thought.

Answer (score 2):

Is using Javascript ok?

`text-overflow` only works in table cells if there is a fixed width. The following snippet sets the `max-width` of the `span` to the correct width.

Place this in your `flip` function and in a `resize` event listener (if the containing div does not have a fixed width).

```
 txt.style["max-width"] = "calc(" + wrap.clientWidth + "px - " + right.clientWidth +"px)";
```

Youu will also have to add `white-space: nowrap` to your `#txt` style.

```js
function Hack() {
    var x = 0,
        n = 150,
        t = 'sample ',
        wrap  = document.querySelector('#wrap'),
        left  = document.querySelector('#left'),
        right = document.querySelector('#right'),
        txt   = document.querySelector('#txt'),
        ent   = document.querySelectorAll('.entry'),
        log   = document.querySelector('#log'),
        run   = document.querySelector('#run'),
        rt    = document.querySelector('#rt')
    ;
    this.rt = parseInt(rt.value) || 1000;
    function getComp(e) {
        var x = window.getComputedStyle(e, null);
        return ''+
          ~~(parseInt(x.getPropertyValue('height'))) + 'x' +
          ~~(parseInt(x.getPropertyValue('width')))
        ;
    }
    this.status = function () {
        log.textContent = 'Height / Width for:\n' +
            '  wrap  : ' + getComp(wrap) + '\n' +
            '  left  : ' + getComp(left) + '\n' +
            '  right : ' + getComp(right) + '\n' +
            '  sample: ' + getComp(txt) + '\n'
        ;
    }
    /* Change between long and short text in sample cells. */
    this.flip = function () {
        txt.textContent = x ? t : (new Array(n)).join(t);
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(ent, function (e) {
            e.textContent = x ? 'abc' : 'abcabc';
        });
        txt.style["max-width"] = "calc(" + wrap.clientWidth + "px - " + right.clientWidth +"px)";
        x ^= 1;
        this.status();
    }
    /* Toggle auto run. */
    this.toggle = function (r) {
        this.rt = parseInt(rt.value);
        if (!this.rt || this.rt < 10)
            rt.value = this.rt = 100;
        clearInterval(this.ttt);
        if (run.checked)
            this.ttt = setInterval(this.flip.bind(this), this.rt);
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', this.flip.bind(this));
    run.addEventListener('click', this.toggle.bind(this));
    rt.addEventListener('change', this.toggle.bind(this, 1));
    this.toggle();
}
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var hack = new Hack();
    hack.flip();
});
```

```css
*       { margin     : 0;    padding : 0;  }
#log    { margin     : 5pt;  border  : 1px solid #ccc; }
#filler { margin-top : 90px; height  : 2000px; background : #efefef; }
label,
input   { cursor     : pointer; }

/* inner elements of cells in right  -- (B)     */
.hdr,
.entry  { padding    : 2px 5px; }
.hdr    { font-weight: bold; }

#wrap { /* the red thing             -- aka (the box) */
    position   : fixed;
    top        : 135px;
    height     : 23px;
    background : #600;
    color      : #999;
    height     : 20px;
    width      : 100%;
    display    : table-row;
}
#left { /* the green thing           -- aka (A) */
    background : #044;
    display    : table-cell;
    width      : 100%;
}
#txt { /* sample text in left                   */  /* Where I want ellipsis */
    display    : block;
    height     : 20px;
    width      : 100%;
    overflow   : hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#right { /* the purple / blue thing  -- aka (B) */
    background : rgba(0,0,200,.5);
    height     : 20px;
    display    : table-cell;
    width      : 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>Click document to expand text, or auto-run:</p>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="run" checked /><label for="run">Change every </label>
<input type="number" id="rt" value="1000" step="100" /> millisecond.
</div>
<pre id="log"></pre>

<!-- The box -->

<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left">
    <span id="txt">sample <!-- ellipsis here --> </span>     
  </div>
  <div id="right">
      <span class="hdr">Foo</span><span class="entry">abcd</span>
      <span class="hdr">Bar</span><span class="entry">abcd</span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- EOF: The box -->

<div id="filler">dummy filler page height</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. And, no, not really. Would like to do it without JS – but seems like that is a goner. Reverted to absolute *right/B* with fixed width (which gets updated by JS on need) and *left/A* with margin-right set to width of A. Case is that `A` is going to be updated very often (at times) and `B` rather seldom in comparison. As such I found it better to fix the width when `B` is changed. – But, all that said – if JS is the only way, it is. I'll accept if no other CSS only solutions comes along.

Comment: Note that the table-layout is not a requirement, far from it. Found it more a hassle then anything else – but thought I had a solution with it. The *requirement* is the description as per the ASII drawing.